# Not Receiving code in Firebase Phone Authentication.

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to implement Firebase phone auth in my app.
I referred the firebase android documents on GitHub, but I can't get the code by SMS.

I don't know why it is happening? I'm testing it on a real device.

Also, I'm sending SMS to another one because the real device doesn't have a sim card. But I'm sure that it's not a problem. Is it right?

This is my code

```
 void logIn(){

    mCallbacks = new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {

        @Override
        public void onVerificationCompleted(PhoneAuthCredential credential) {
            // This callback will be invoked in two situations:
            // 1 - Instant verification. In some cases the phone number can be instantly
            //     verified without needing to send or enter a verification code.
            // 2 - Auto-retrieval. On some devices Google Play services can automatically
            //     detect the incoming verification SMS and perform verificaiton without
            //     user action.
            Log.d("verification", "onVerificationCompleted:" + credential);
            // [START_EXCLUDE silent]
            mVerificationInProgress = false;
            // [END_EXCLUDE]

            // [START_EXCLUDE silent]
            // Update the UI and attempt sign in with the phone credential
            // [END_EXCLUDE]
            signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential);
        }

        @Override
        public void onVerificationFailed(FirebaseException e) {
            // This callback is invoked in an invalid request for verification is made,
            // for instance if the the phone number format is not valid.
            Log.w("verification", "onVerificationFailed", e);
            // [START_EXCLUDE silent]
            mVerificationInProgress = false;
            // [END_EXCLUDE]

            if (e instanceof FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {

            } else if (e instanceof FirebaseTooManyRequestsException) {
                // The SMS quota for the project has been exceeded
                // [START_EXCLUDE]
                Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), "Quota exceeded.",
                        Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // [END_EXCLUDE]
            }


        }

        @Override
        public void onCodeSent(String verificationId,
                               PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken token) {
            // The SMS verification code has been sent to the provided phone number, we
            // now need to ask the user to enter the code and then construct a credential
            // by combining the code with a verification ID.
            Log.d("verification", "onCodeSent:" + verificationId);

            // Save verification ID and resending token so we can use them later
            mVerificationId = verificationId;
            mResendToken = token;


        }
    };

    PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
            "+79995198722",        // Phone number to verify
            60,                 // Timeout duration
            TimeUnit.SECONDS,   // Unit of timeout
            this,               // Activity (for callback binding)
            mCallbacks);        // OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks

    mVerificationInProgress = true;
}

private void verifyPhoneNumberWithCode(String verificationId, String code) {
    // [START verify_with_code]
    PhoneAuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(verificationId, code);
    // [END verify_with_code]
    signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential);
}


private void signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(PhoneAuthCredential credential) {
    mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                        Log.d("signIn", "signInWithCredential:success");

                        FirebaseUser user = task.getResult().getUser();

                    } else {
                        // Sign in failed, display a message and update the UI
                        Log.w("signIn", "signInWithCredential:failure", task.getException());
                        if (task.getException() instanceof FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {

                        }

                    }
                }
            });
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: nice, Frank edited but not helper.. ingineer ....

Comment: Check if the number is added as testing number in firebase console. If so, you will not get the sms.

Answer (score 7):

I think your problem might be **SHA-1 finger print**, So you need to update the SHA-1 key in Firebase console.

**Steps:**

After login to [Firebase console](https://console.firebase.google.com)

1. Click on your project then you can see Overview of your project
2. Click on 3 dots and click Settings
3. Click Add Finger print (At bottom)
4. Paste your SHA-1 key click on Save.

**Steps to SHA-1 key:**

1. Select gradle in Android Studio from left panel
2. Select your App
3. Go to Tasks -> android -> signingReport

then you can see the Sha-1 key.

[image]

Comment: Solved my issue!

Comment: Glad it helped you. ;)

Comment: Hey @ShylendraMadda, Thanks for this but I have a question,
 should I add SHA-1 and SHA-256 to project settings? and after adding them should i build a new release or old release will work?

Comment: @OliverD Yes, you should add SHA-1 and no need to build a new app.

Comment: @ShylendraMadda  I do it but I can't get the SMS :((

Comment: @OliverD You need to use the same SHA-1 key which you build your released APK for play store. Check it once?

Comment: after you upload app to  playstore you will need the release SHA1 key also...otherwise the app will not send sms too.

Comment: @AbdulWahid you were right. As soon as I added the release key to firebase settings and used new google-services json, phone auth started working.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by running an app on a real machine(Android Device) instead of an emulator.

Comment: OP did specify that they are testing on a real device.